# загрузка фото пользователя laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

как обработать загрузку фото профиля пользователя

```
<form action="{{ route('updateuser') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="grid">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="item data-photo">
                        <div class="data-name-profile">
                            <div class="file-upload">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="file" name="newphoto" id="photo" value="{{ $profile->attributes->photo }}">
                                    <span>Редактировать фото</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item data-info">
                        <div class="data-contacts">
                            <p>День рождения: <span>{{ $profile->attributes->birthday }}</span></p>
                            <p>Город: <span>{{ $profile->attributes->city }}</span></p>
                            <p>Номер телефона: <span>{{ $profile->attributes->phone }}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item data-save">

                        <div class="data-item date">
                            <label for="">Дата рождения:</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="14 сентября 1992" name="birthday" value="{{ $profile->attributes->birthday }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-item">
                            <label for="">Город:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Москва" name="city" value="{{ $profile->attributes->city }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-item">
                            <label for="">Номер телефона:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="14 сентября 1992" name="phone" value="{{ $profile->attributes->phone }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-item cart">
                            <label for="">Номер карты или Яндекс-кошелек::</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="410017100674849" name="pay" value="{{ $profile->attributes->pay }}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="data-lesson">
                            <p class="title">Интересующие предметы:</p>
                            <div class="item">
                                <label for="">Экзамен/цель</label>
                                <select name="sessia" id="" class="select">
                                    <option value="">ЕГЭ</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <label for="">Предмет</label>
                                <select name="training" id="" class="select">
                                    <option value="">Математика</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-green">Сохранить изменения</button>
                    </div>
                </form>\
```

в таблице users есть поле photo, как в контроллере обработать и перекинуть фото в папку images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Простой вариант:**

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/avatars/');
    $fileName = $user->id . '.jpg'; 

    $request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->image  = $destinationPath . $fileName;
    $user->save();
}
```

**Если надо хранить аватар нескольких размеров, я сделал так:**

Я использую [Intervention Image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) для работы с картинками.

В бд есть столбец avatar:

```
$table->json('avatar')->nullable();
```

В модели:

```
protected $casts = [
    'avatar' => 'array'
];
```

Создал trait для того чтобы менять avatar(он у меня менялся не только в одном контроллере)

```php
namespace App\Traits;
use File;

trait Avatar
{
    /**
     * Ставит аватарку под все размеры
     */
    public function setUserAvatar($user, $img) { // TODO interface Image
        // сохраняет начальный статус(когда только обрезана)
        $img->backup();

        $sizes = [
            'lg' => 320,
            'md' => 200,
            'sm' => 133,
            'circle' => 80
        ];

        $avatar = [];
        foreach ($sizes as $sizeName => $width) {
            $avatar[$sizeName] = $this->saveAvatarBySize($user, $img, $sizeName, $width);
        }
        $user->avatar = $avatar; // json поле для аватарок
        $user->save();


        return $avatar;
    }


    protected function saveAvatarBySize($user, $img, $sizeName, $width) {
        $folderPath =  "avatars/$user->id";
        $folderPathFull = public_path($folderPath);
        $filePath = "$folderPath/$sizeName.jpg";

        if (!File::exists($folderPathFull)) {
            File::makeDirectory($folderPathFull, 0777, true, true);
        }

        $img->resize($width, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path($filePath));
        // возвращает к состоянию когда был сделан бэкап $img->backup() (тогда была только обрезаность)
        $img->reset();


        return config('app.url') . '/' . $filePath . '?' . rand();
    }
}
```

Потом в контроллер добавил trait:

```
use App\Traits\Avatar;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    use Avatar;
```

И в методе роута делал так:

```
public function setAvatar(SaveAvatarRequest $request) {
    $user = auth()->user();
    $cropInfo = json_decode($request->cropInfo, true);
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $img = Image::make($file);
    // Если у Вас есть данные для crop
    // ->crop(
    //     $cropInfo['width'],
    //     $cropInfo['height'],
    //     $cropInfo['x'],
    //     $cropInfo['y']
    // );

    $avatar = $this->setUserAvatar($user, $img);

    // это я возвращал измененного пользователя
    // return new UserResource($user);
}
```

Comment: оу, слишком тяжело)

Comment: а вот это зачем? request->hasFile('photo'))

Comment: Первый вариант не сложный. Вы можете определить, присутствует ли файл в запросе с использованием метода hasFile. Во втором примере я не делал это проверку потому что проверял файл в [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)(SaveAvatarRequest ) с использованием [этого](image) правила.

Comment: такой вопрос, я проверил и записал в базу + перекинул в базу, но в профиле фотка не появляется пока не нажал ctrl+f5

Comment: это потому что ссылка одинаковая. Добавьте к адресу `. '?' . rand()`

Comment: к какому адресу?

Comment: Адресу аватарки, ссылки, которую передаете пользователю, а то она кешируется если у нее одинаковый адрес.

Comment: $fileName = $user->id. '?' . rand() . '.jpg';  так?

Comment: Если у Вас код из моео примера то так: `$user->image  = $destinationPath . $fileName . '?' . rand();`

Comment: вот так у меня
if ($request->hasFile('newphoto')) {
            $destinationPath = 'img/avatars/';
            $fileName = Auth::user()->id . '.jpg';
            $request->file('newphoto')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $photo  = $destinationPath . $fileName;
        }else $photo = Auth::user()->attributes->photo;

Comment: хотя знаете у меня со всей формой так, пока не нажмешь ctrl + f5 данные новые не появляются

Comment: `$photo = $destinationPath . $fileName . '?' . rand();`

Comment: а как проверить правильность токена в методе?

Comment: Какого токена? Может это уже отдельный вопрос? Этому не забудьте поставить галочку если он Вам помог.